# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT as multiple fields and custom order

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

Here is a structure of my tables:
[image: Tables structure]

Here is what I want as a result of a query (considering that user provides me with `2|4|1` pattern):
[image: Result of a query]

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT parcel.TrackCode, parcelType.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(track.DateTime SEPARATOR '|') AS dt
FROM track
JOIN parcel ON track.ParcelID = parcel.ID
JOIN parcelType ON parcel.ParcelTypeID = parcelType.ID
JOIN event ON track.EventID = event.ID
GROUP BY parcel.ID;
```

The result is:

[image: Result]

So the problem is that I need GROUP_CONCAT() to divide data to several fields (`date where track.eventID = 3`, `date where track.eventID = 1`, `date where track.eventID = 5`, `date where track.eventID = 7` # considering that the pattern is `3|1|5|7`). Any ideas?

Comment: Are there always only 3 events that the user needs to see?

Comment: No, the pattern could be 3|2|5|4|1|7. Changed the 2nd pattern example to make this more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh. Is there a maximum number of items in the pattern?

Comment: If you have a finite number of event types, why not summarize for all of them at once, and then just choose the fields the user wants?

Comment: @HolgerBrandt This pattern is defined in the configuration file and the number of items is not limited.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Didn't get it. Could you explain this more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest running two queries.  First this one, to get the relevant events:

```
SELECT ParcelID, EventID, DateTime
FROM track
WHERE EventID IN(1, 2, 4)
```

Store the results of this query in a map of parcel ids to arrays of events where the key is the parcel ID and the value is another array. In that inner array, the key is the event ID and the value is the event date.

```
array(1 => array(
        2 => '2012-05-15 15:33:00', 
        4 => '2012-05-22 11:35:41', 
        1 => '2012-05-04 18:58:30'
    ),
    2 => array(
        2 => '2012-07-01 09:05:56', 
        4 => '2012-07-14 13:32:00', 
        1 => '2012-06-27 12:44:32'
    )
);
```

Then, use a query like this next one to get the list of parcels, and for each one, you can easily look in memory at the results of the previous query to find out the dates of each of those events, for any given parcel ID.

```
SELECT parcel.ID, parcel.TrackCode, parceltype.Name
FROM parcel
JOIN parceltype ON parceltype.ID = parcel.ParcelTypeID
```

*Note: this answer is a trimmed version of the [conversation that took place in the MySQL chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4655577#4655577)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want the IDs also, you should `GROUP_CONCAT` the ids from track, they will be given in the same order too.

Or set an ORDER BY at the end of the query and it will manipulate that data as well.

Comment: I don't need the EventIDs, but I need Dates according to EventIDs in one row and with custom order pattern (like `4|2|1|5` (`Date WHERE EventId = 4|Date WHERE EventId = 2|Date WHERE EventId = 1|Date WHERE EventId = 5`))